Using NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl from LWC
I'm trying to use NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl from an LWC to open a link to an external url e.g. https://google.com
The issue i am seeing is Salesforce opens a new window and appends my URL to the org
e.g https://computing-inspiration-XXXX.scratch.lightning.force.com/lightning/webpage/https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
Below is an extract from my LWC:
urlString = 'https://google.com';

this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
type: 'standard__webPage',
attributes: {
    url: urlString.toString()
    }
}).then((url) => {
    window.open(url,'_blank');
});

Can anyone provide any guidance here? from the documentation / examples i have seen this should work.

How is this different from your previous question?

@DerekF different navigation method, different outcome due to using GenerateUrl that results in different error.

why are you complicating things.
you can just use lightning-formatted-text and set your URL as value and set linkify=true or just add linkify.
